# Why can't i see true or false in console

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I've wroten a bIt code and I got help a bit. I thing code is working correctly but I can't see true or false In the console why? it should give one of them(true or false). Maybe i'm calling method a wrong way. Could you please explain where am i doing wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = new int[4][4];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number");

    for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++ )
        {
            array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int[] rad : array)
    {
        for(int column: rad)
        {
            System.out.print(column+" ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    symetrisk(array);
}
public static boolean symetrisk(int[][] f){
    for (int out = 0; out < f.length; out++) {
        for (int in = 0; in < f[out].length; in++) {
            if (f.length != f[out].length || (f[out][in] != f[in][out])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You are just returning true or false, you are not printing anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of the `main` method, you are calling the method `symetrisk`:

```
symetrisk(array);
```

But you are not doing anything with the return value of this method, so it just gets ignored. If you want it to print the return value, then `System.out.println(...)` it:

```
System.out.println(symetrisk(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

You never print the result of call to `symetrisk`.

Try with:

```
System.out.println(symetrisk(array));
```

Or safe the result to a variable and print it after:

```
boolean result = symetrisk(array);
System.out.println(result);
```